# Relation between boolean blind SQLi and time blind SQLi?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection

I am part of a team which developing web app penetration testing framework, and I am taking care of SQLi detection. When I tested multiple known vulnerable local sites found **Boolean Blind flaw always occur with Time Blind flaw**. I want to know is my conclusion is correct or is there a situation where a Boolean Blind can occur without Time Blind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I don't think I can provide a concrete example my inclination would be to say that it is possible that there would be an instance of SQLi where boolean based injection would be possible and time-based would not.

The reason being that time-based injection usually relies on modifying the syntax of the query to add additional statements (e.g. WAITFOR DELAY) which may not be supported in every part of a query in every DBMS, whereas boolean based injection relies on inserting logical operators which are more likely to be universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

There are two terms that we are talking about here:

1. **Boolean Blind** : In this technique, we aim to detect sqli by passing values into the input parameters which will return true or false. For eg, if I give  the input as 10=10 or A||B, then the application will return the results after executing that expression. If it does, then it is vulnerable to SQLi.
2. **Time Blind**: This is used to detect vulnerablity by forcing the application to wait for some time and then return the results. Fo eg, WaitFor Delay.

Both the above techniques are a part of Blind SQL Injection technique.